# Trouble in using gltf-model in aframe-react

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, gltf, aframe-react, react-pannellum

I'm using aframe-react

3D - model is not rendering in the browser, it's showing a blank screen with no errors.

```
<Entity gltf-model={{src: 'https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf'}}/>
```

I don't know whether it supports or not? if so, is there any alternative for this?

https://aframe.io/docs/1.5.0/components/gltf-model.html

i tried this step to,

please suggest the solution or any other alternatives.